# проблема при обучении модели python torchvision densenet161

Tags: python

Программа работает при обучении torchvision моделей `resnet18(pretrained=True)` и `vgg16(pretrained=True)`. При обучении `densenet161(pretrained=True)` возникает ошибка:

> Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0! (when checking argument for argument mat1 in method wrapper_CUDA_addmm). device = 'cuda'. model = model.to(device). X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)

Comment: В ошибке написано, что часть тензоров у вас загружена в `CPU`, а часть в `GPU`. Проверьте, куда у вас загружены данные, в частности `X` и `y` до той строчки которая в ошибке.

Comment: print(dev, X.get_device(), y.get_device()): cuda:0 0 0;  y_hat = net(X): 'RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0! (when checking argument for argument mat1 in method wrapper_CUDA_addmm)'

Comment: А вы где-то `.cuda()` в коде используете? Если да, почитайте вот это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091226/runtimeerror-expected-all-tensors-to-be-on-the-same-device-but-found-at-least